# Issues with foreach inside of email

Tags: php, email, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am attempting to create an email that sends to each of the users with the group of 5. I want the email to send to each user in that group...not sure if I am doing that here?

Anyways, the email does not get sent. I get an error about my foreach argument, which I looked up, but cannot figure out how to structure it. All I'm wanting it to do is to echo the usernames from my user_players table in the order they are in the table.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$order_stmt= $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users, user_players WHERE 'users.group'=5");
$order_stmt->execute() or
        die('Draft order email execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($draft_stmt1->error));

    $order_row = $order_stmt->fetch();

    $order_id = $order_row['id'];
    $order_firstname = $order_row['firstname'];
    $order_lastname = $order_row['lastname'];
    $order_username = $order_row['username'];
    $order_email = $order_row['email'];
    $order_group = $order_row['group'];

    $to = $order_email;
    $subject = 'Draft Order';
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Draft Order</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi '.$order_firstname.',</p><br>
        <p>The draft order has been created. This is a completely randomized selection.</p>
        <p>The draft order is of the following:</p><br>';
        foreach($order_row as $order) {
            echo $order_username;
        }
        $message .='<p>Thank you,</p>
        <p>Administration</p>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    $from = "user-requests@example.com";
    $Bcc = "user-requests-confirm@example.com";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'To: ' .$to. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$Bcc. "\r\n";

    // Send the email
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

UPDATE:

```
user_players
CREATE TABLE `user_players` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player1` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player2` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player3` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player4` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player5` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player6` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player7` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player8` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player9` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player10` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player11` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player12` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player13` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `player14` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=158 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


    users
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
 `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=95 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Should be  echo `$order['order_username']`

Comment: Also when I comment out the foreach, I do not get any errors and it does not send the email out. I'm not sure if it doesn't send at all, but it doesn't reach me and I am group 5.

Comment: @aldrin27 I still get the same error with that in it.

Comment: Can you print_r($order_row)?

Comment: I tried doing it here... `$order_row = $order_stmt->fetch();
  print_r($order_row);` and nothing printed out.

Comment: Maybe the query of select * from is the cause try to check it carefully or maybe the table has no record because as u said nothing printed

Comment: The table definitely has records. How could I check that query?

Comment: Do you have column `users.group`?

Comment: I have the column group in the users table.

Comment: Can you give me the column of your tables?

Comment: There's a lot, I will be normalizing it soon, but I added them to my question.

Comment: Your query should be `SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'group'=5`

Comment: I need the user_players table selected too though because I need to echo out the users in the order they are in that.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Join the tables. Use sql JOIN

Comment: Like this? `$order_stmt= $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users
 INNER JOIN user_players 
 WHERE 'users.group'=5")` ?

Comment: here's the link for SQL JOIN http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I tried that and added `or die("Could not prepare email: " . mysqli_error($con));` under the prepare line, it did not throw any errors. It did however, throw the same `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in` error.

Comment: Try to implement this `SELECT*
FROM users
INNER JOIN user_players
ON users.id=user_players.user_id;`

Comment: Ok, I did this... `$order_stmt= $con->prepare("SELECT users.*, user_players.*
 FROM users
 INNER JOIN user_players
 ON users.id=user_players.user_id
 WHERE users.group=5")` and I am getting something to echo out, but it is only the user_id. Not everything else in there.

Comment: Do I need to add a while loop or anything? Only the first user_id is printing out

Comment: I added the while loop and the correct amount of records are showing, but it only echoes out the number 1, which I thought originally was just displaying my id, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. Do the while loop

Comment: Do you know why it is only showing the number 1? I have three users in that group, so it is showing the number 1 three times. The foreach error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

(Removed original answer as my PHP is rusty.)

You have an array called $order_row:

```
 foreach($order_row as $order) {
        echo $order[‘Field Name in Table’];
 }
```

Also, see this post: [PHP SQL Foreach Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476682/php-sql-foreach-statement)

Comment: Why would you want to create another empty array?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, LOTS of issues but lets start with the main ones: Your schema AND your SQL.

By looking at your database dump, i don't see why the tables should be separated. Unless you want to have more than 1 `user_players` per `users` the model is wrong. Also if you want to form a "team" of `users` (and that is the reason for the inmoral amount of `playerX` fields), i think it should be better with a `team` table and make a Many to Many relationship (or One to Many if users can only exist on a single team) between `team` and `users`.

I don't want to keep fixing something that has a significative foundation flaw, but if you can't or won't change your database model (and also because i like a good challenge) then try this instead: `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN user_players ON users.id=user_players.user_id WHERE users.group=5`

The `execute or die()` is useless because, as far as i know, even if it returns a empty result set, it worked! In other words the `die()` only executes when it cannot connect to the database or another similar exception. Also `or die()` is not a good practice, is better if you ask `if (!empty(order_row))` and encapsulate the rest of the code inside the `if` and put an `else` showing the error. (this is the reason your `foreach` fails, it expects an array but gets an empty or null variable).

<strike>Now, according to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):</strike>

> public mixed PDOStatement::**fetch** ([ **int $fetch_style** [, int
>   $cursor_orientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT [, int $cursor_offset = 0
>   ]]] )
>
> Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object.
>
> **fetch_style** Controls how the next row will be returned to the caller. This value must be one of the PDO::FETCH_* constants,
>   defaulting to value of PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to
>   PDO::FETCH_BOTH).
>
> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set.

That means `$order_row = $order_stmt->fetch();` returns both and associative and a numbered array of a **single row** (this will be important later), in other words, **every single value will be repeated**:

```
//PDO::FETCH_BOTH: Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number.
Array (
    [name] => banana
    [0] => banana
    [colour] => yellow
    [1] => yellow
)
```

Change it to this: `$order_row = $order_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to have only an associative array with the field name as key. The problem is because of the `INNER JOIN` of the SQL, repeated fields (id, username, firstname, lastname, email) will only show once and only from the "left" part (`users`).

### EDIT

Sorry i mistook your use of `prepare` and `execute` as PDO, the thing is, with `mysqli` there's a very important step that you missed, if you see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), you'll find this gems:

> Fetch the result from a prepared statement into the variables bound by *mysqli_stmt_bind_result()*.

and:

```
Return Values 
Value   Description 
TRUE    Success. Data has been fetched
FALSE   Error occurred 
NULL    No more rows/data exists or data truncation occurred
```

That means, the reason you only got `1` as every result is because `fetch` returns `TRUE` (equivalent to `1`) for every successful fetch, and you say you have 3 records, do the math. But if you use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php), then you have to know every column and the order of them to set the values to variables, let's do this instead:

```
$order_stmt->execute();
$order_result = $order_stmt->get_result();
$order_row = $order_result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)
```

### END_EDIT

But reading your comments you only want the `playerX` data, now that we have an associative array, do a [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) against a [regex of the key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$players = array_filter(function($key){
    return preg_match('/^player',$key) === 1;
},$order_row,ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Now that we have an array containing only the players we can [randomize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) it (as you say in the mail) and do a proper `foreach` of it.

But before that look at this simplified code:

```
$message = "I'm saving text in a variable";
foreach ($array as $value){
    echo "i'm echoing a $value";
}
$message .= "I'm concatenating in the same variable as before!";
```

See the error? If you expect the `foreach` to `echo` the data into the message, this is plain wrong. Because `echo` outputs to the user... in the browser. In other words, the `foreach` doesn't even know `$message` exists!

Do this instead:

```
$random_keys = array_rand($players, 5) //here we get our 5 lucky victims
$message = " Put here the same part of the email but do this at the end:<br>
    <ul>";
foreach ($random_keys as $key){ //so you only iterate 5 times
    $message .= "<li>I'm putting every {$players[$key]} in a nice list</li><br>";
}
$message .= "</ul>
    put here the last part of the email.";
```

And DONE!, now you send the email... wait, WHAT! you also need to repeat this email for everyone in a group?

EASY!

Remember i said something about remembering something?

> That means `$order_row = $order_stmt->fetch();` returns both and associative and a numbered array of a *single row* (**this will be important later**)

all you need to do is put the `if` i mentioned before (the one where you check if the result row came out empty) inside a `while` that is looping over the result set of every one in the group:

```
while($order_row = $order_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
    if(!empty($order_row)){
        // assign the variables, format the message and send the email...
    } else {
        echo 'The query is bad and i should feel bad or the database has no records for this group';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate all of your help. This is one of the best answers I have seen, but I have all of my code on Object Orriented mysqli and do not know how to write in PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$order_row = $order_stmt->fetch();` to `$order_row = $order_stmt->fetch_assoc();`

Then in your foreach loop, change `echo $order_username;` to `echo $order['username'];`

Comment: When I do that, I get this... `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() `

Comment: Use `fetch_assoc` instead of `fetchAll`

Comment: I thought that you can only use `fetch` with a prepared statement?